# VBA Saving single sheet as CSV (not whole workbook)

Tags: vba, excel

I appreciate there are lots of entries like [save individual excel sheets as csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331624/save-individual-excel-sheets-as-csv)
and [Export each sheet to a separate csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434994/export-each-sheet-to-a-separate-csv-file) - But I want to save a **single worksheet** in a workbook.

My code in my xlsm file has a params and data sheet. I create a worksheet copy of the data with pasted values and then want to save it as csv. Currently my whole workbook changes name and becomes a csv.

**How do I "save as csv" a single sheet in an Excel workbook?**

Is there a `Worksheet.SaveAs` or do I have to move my data sheet to another workbook and save it that way?

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
' [Sample so some DIMs and parameters passed in left out] 
Dim s1 as Worksheet
Dim s2 as Worksheet

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet)
' copy across
s1.Range(s1.Cells(1, 1), s1.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy

' Create new empty worksheet for holding values
Set s2 = Worksheets.Add

s2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

' save sheet
s2.Activate
strFullname = strPath & strFilename


' >>> BIT THAT NEEDS FIXIN'
s2.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, _
     FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True

' Can I do Worksheets.SaveAs?
```

Using Windows 10 and Office 365

Comment: If you use the Worksheet.Copy method, without setting a paste destination, Excel will open it as a new workbook, only containing that sheet. After Worksheet.Copy, you can simply use ActiveWorkbook, as the copied sheets workbook becomes the active workbook, and from there save it as a new CSV file.

Comment: Amazing - 2500 views and not a single vote...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This code works fine for me.

```
Sub test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

It's making a copy of the entire strSourceSheet sheet, which opens a new workbook, which we can then save as a .csv file, then it closes the newly saved .csv file, not messing up file name on your original file.

Comment: Thanks @Alex4336. I added to the close. 
    `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`
    
    _# And remove temp worksheet in xlsm_
   `s2.Delete`

Comment: That was just a quick draft, so feel free to use it how you like :)
The above code doesn't need to delete s2, as it won't create s2 in the first place.

Comment: Excellent answer, Alex.  It helped a lot. I'll just add that the Copy command creates a new workbook called something like "Book1.xlsx", with just the copied sheet in it.  That new workbook becomes the ActiveWorkbook.  Once you Close it, the ActiveWorkbook again becomes your original code-running workbook, which is still open and unchanged.

Comment: For those wondering what `CreateBackup:=True` is for, it creates a backup of the CSV file that the `SaveAs` call overwrites (it's called "Backup of myfile.xlk" for me)

Comment: if you want to make the CSV file such that it can be converted to an ICS file (for calendar purposes), you need the file format `FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS`

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly generic

```
Sub WriteCSVs()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    myPath = "\\myserver\myfolder\"

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet.Index).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & mySheet.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next mySheet

'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may work, OP specifically asks to export *only one* sheet in the workbook

Answer (score 3):

You just need to save the workbook as a CSV file.
Excel will pop up a dialog warning that you are saving to a single sheet, but you can suppress the warning with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False.`

Don't forget to put it back to true though.

Comment: Thanks @PaulG. I am used to getting that prompt when doing it manually in Excel but the code is renaming my file with no prompt which was weird

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs... is saving the sheet (with a prompt that a file will be overwritten) but it is also renaming my xlsm mothership file to the csv file name in the root directory! So I am still stuck

Comment: Hmmm are you sure you are renaming the file to a csv correctly (with the CSV extension? So if the original workbook is Book1.xlsx, try something like:   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\temp\Book1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: yes filename is "unitprices.csv" with full path in front. It is saving in strPath and also renaming my xlsm file with this name and extension as well (in another location). Might be a bug of setting S2 with Thisworkbook...?

Comment: That's strange, what happens if you try a different csv name. Try saving as Test.csv. Does that rename the original xlsx file?

Comment: the original xlsm workbook has a different name to the csv and it still renames it. It looks like I have to do the new workbook thing

Comment: Oh, I see - my mistake I didn't realize you wanted both the original and the copy. You should just be able to save a copy but as a CSV file. Something like  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Book1.csv"

Answer (score 2):

Coming to this question several years later, I have found a method that works much better for myself.  This is because the worksheet(s) I'm trying to save are large and full of calculations, and they take an inconvenient amount of time to copy to a new sheet.

In order to speed up the process, it saves the current worksheet and then simply reopens it, closing the unwanted .csv window:

```
Sub SaveThisSheetInParticular()

Dim path As String
path = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Worksheets("<Sheet Name>").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\<File Name>", FileFormat:=xlCSV

Application.Workbooks.Open (path)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks("<File Name>.csv").Close

End Sub
```

Here the Sheet and csv filename are hardcoded, since nobody but the macro creator (me) should be messing with them.  However, it could just as easily be changed to store and use the Active Sheet name in order to export the current sheet whenever the macro is called.

Note that you can do this with multiple sheets, you simply have to use the last filename in the close statement:

```
Worksheets("<Sheet 1>").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\<File 1>", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Worksheets("<Sheet 2>").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\<File 2>", FileFormat:=xlCSV

[...]

Workbooks("<File 2>.csv").Close
```