# Outputting multiple CSV files for all but one worksheet in VBA and renaming

Tags: vba, csv, output

I've got 4 separate worksheets - one that is titled main, one that is titled Data 1, one that is titled Data 2 and one that is titled Data 3.

I have a button on the main sheet that when I click transforms all three of the Data Sheets using the same function but what I'm stuck on is that I also want it to transform the 3 data sheets into 3 separate CSV files with the names "output_data1.csv", "output_data2.csv" and "output_data3.csv" but also for it to be flexible enough to work on another data sheet 4 if I add it in later.

Is there any way that I can do this? The main thing that I'm stuck on is being able to rename it as well but keep the original excel file unchanged.

```
Sub DumpOutput()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
        ProcessData ws
    End If
Next ws
End Sub

Sub ProcessData(ByRef w As Worksheet)
Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction, M As Long
Dim i As Long, J As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer
 N = Columns.Count
 M = Rows.Count
With w
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
           If wf.CountBlank(.Columns(i)) <> M Then Exit For
    Next i

    For J = i To 1 Step -1
        If wf.CountBlank(.Columns(J)) = M Then
            .Cells(1, J).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next J

    For J = M To 1 Step -1
         If wf.CountBlank(.Rows(J)) <> N Then Exit For
    Next J

        For i = J To 1 Step -1
            If wf.CountBlank(.Rows(i)) = N Then
        .Cells(1, i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    nams = Array("NAME", "TICKER", "PRICE", "CURRENCY", "ISIN", "TYPE")
    Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        For J = i To rng.Columns.Count
            For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
                If nams(F) = rng(J) Then Dex = F: Exit For
            Next F

        If F < i Then
            Temp = rng.Columns(i).Value
            rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value
            rng(J).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = Temp
        End If
        Next J
    Next i



    .Range("f1:f13") = Application.Transpose(Array("TYPE", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index"))
    w.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Debug.Print .Name
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can show the code/function that you already have, it will be much easier to help you resolve the problem...

Comment: Hi, I've added in the code if that helps. I basically want it to turn it into csv  files after all the transformations are complete.

Comment: Have a look at the answer provided by Siddarth in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928984/save-specific-single-sheet-as-csv

Comment: That should give you what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understood it correctly, I think that it wouldn't work if I added another Data4?

Comment: Added an answer for you - should work for whatever worksheets you add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are passing the worksheet directly into the function, you can apply a small change to the `Sub` to do as you require, for however many and whichever worksheets you pass into it:

```
Sub ProcessData(ByRef w As Worksheet)
Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction, M As Long
Dim i As Long, J As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer
 N = Columns.Count
 M = Rows.Count
With w
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
           If wf.CountBlank(.Columns(i)) <> M Then Exit For
    Next i

    For J = i To 1 Step -1
        If wf.CountBlank(.Columns(J)) = M Then
            .Cells(1, J).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next J

    For J = M To 1 Step -1
         If wf.CountBlank(.Rows(J)) <> N Then Exit For
    Next J

        For i = J To 1 Step -1
            If wf.CountBlank(.Rows(i)) = N Then
        .Cells(1, i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    nams = Array("NAME", "TICKER", "PRICE", "CURRENCY", "ISIN", "TYPE")
    Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        For J = i To rng.Columns.Count
            For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
                If nams(F) = rng(J) Then Dex = F: Exit For
            Next F

        If F < i Then
            Temp = rng.Columns(i).Value
            rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value
            rng(J).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = Temp
        End If
        Next J
    Next i



    .Range("f1:f13") = Application.Transpose(Array("TYPE", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Index"))
    w.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Debug.Print .Name
End With

' Now make a copy of the Worksheet to a new workbook
w.Copy
' And save the newly created workbook with that sheet as a csv
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\myPath\" & w.Name & ".csv", _
                  FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```