# Macro for saving 2 sheets as csv files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup a macro in excel to save two sheets from a work book as an csv file.

I want the file name in the format - WorkBook name - Worksheet name

But I can't even get it to save with the work sheet name yet, I get

Can't access read-only document "filename.csv"

The code is:

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()
savePath = "/Users/****/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Assets/Create Import File/"

For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case xWs.Name
        Case "List"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=savePath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Case "Evolutions"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=savePath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Case Else
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, the frist two `Case` can be combined into one:  `Case "List", "Evolutions"`.

Comment: I know, its left over from where I was also trying to manually define the file names

Comment: `/` in path - is this on a Mac ?

Comment: Yeah, it’s a mac

Comment: Have a look at the method used here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38928984/7446760

Comment: Ron De Bruin is the master of VBA for MACs.  His new site for macs is [macexcel.com](https://macexcel.com/)/.  Here is the relavant page:  [SaveAs and FileFormat numbers on Mac](https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/saveasfileformat/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on Windows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAsCSV()

    Dim savePath As String, s As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    
    savePath = "c:\temp\SO\" '"/Users/****/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Assets/Create Import File/"
    savePath = savePath & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", " - ")
    
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case xWs.Name
            
            Case "List", "Evolutions"
                s = savePath & xWs.Name & ".csv"
                'Debug.Print s
                xWs.Copy
                With ActiveWorkbook
                   .SaveAs Filename:=s, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                   .Close False
                End With

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```